# Removing a field from a form generated by YII2 ActiveForm

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a form generated using YII2 ActiveForm. there are some field I need to be on the if I select certain options , or need to have them removed if I select some other option.

For e.g. I Have a dropdown AccountType, with two options "individual" and "company". 
If the user selects "individual" some fields on the form needs to go away say company name, and some other fields need to appear such as First name, last name. Initially when the display the form , only the Account Type field is there.

below is the code I have at the moment

```
<?php 
 $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'account-setup-form']); ?>
 echo $form->field($modelAccMain, 'account_type')
           ->widget(Select2::classname(), [
            'data' => $accountTypeArray,
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select account type'],
            ]);         
  echo $form->field($modelUsers, 'firstname')->textInput()
            ->hint('')->label('First Name');
  echo $form->field($modelUsers, 'lastname')->textInput()
            ->hint('')->label('Last Name');
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To do this in server you would need to submit the form every time user changes the value of the "AccountType" field. Which is kind of irritating. I suggest using JS for this. You may write some code to show/hide some parts of the form based on the value selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios) for that, first define them in your model and than you can use a if statement in your view

```
if ($model->isAttributeActive('attribute_name')) {
```

But like @nterms wrote, if you want the user to be able to switch on the client side, javascript would be better.

Defining scenarios also helps with the validation (only active attributes will be validated).

p.s. Don't forget to set the scenario in your controller

```
$model = new MyModel(['scenario'=>'my_scenario']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way i would handle it is with jquery hide and show using the change event of the dropdown,

In your javascript

Assuming that the data in the select 2 widget is in the form of array
eg:

```
[1=>"first-item",2=>"second-item",...]

$(document).ready(function(){
var id= //check the id of the select2
```

on the inspect element id using chrome;

```
$("#id").on("change", function(){
    if(id.value==1){
     //show a div
    }else{
     //hide a div
    }

   //for multiple values better use switch

 like this
   switch(id){
    case 1:{
       $("#divid").show();
       ......
       }
       }
})

})
```

I hope you get the idea,

For the select 2 id you can set it via

```
echo $form->field($modelAccMain, 'account_type')
       ->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => $accountTypeArray,
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select account type',"id"=>"mypreffereid"],
        ]);
```